# SbtOsgi AutoPlugin can't be loaded due to type mismatch error

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-osgi

I tried to use the sbt-osgi plugin, but I can't load its `AutoPlugin`, the compiler refuses to compile my code.

First, I added the newest version of the plugin to `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Classpaths.sbtPluginSnapshots
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-osgi" % "0.8.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

After that, I set the sbt version in `project/build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

Then, I created `project/Build.scala` with the following contents:

```
import sbt._
import com.typesafe.sbt.osgi.SbtOsgi

object Build extends sbt.Build {
  lazy val fooProject = Project("foo-project", file("."))
    .enablePlugins(SbtOsgi)
}
```

But this results in the following error message:

```
[info] Loading project definition from .../sbt-osgi-test/project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to .../sbt-osgi-test/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[error] .../sbt-osgi-test/project/Build.scala:10: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.typesafe.sbt.osgi.SbtOsgi.type
[error]  required: sbt.Plugins
[error]     .enablePlugins(SbtOsgi)
[error]                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

This error message doesn't make any sense, because [`AutoPlugin`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/api/index.html#sbt.AutoPlugin) extends `sbt.Plugins`. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the problem is, that the 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT version of the sbt-osgi plugin is broken:

```
% javap -cp ~/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-osgi/jars/sbt-osgi-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.typesafe.sbt.osgi.SbtOsgi$
Compiled from "SbtOsgi.scala"
public final class com.typesafe.sbt.osgi.SbtOsgi$ implements sbt.Plugin {
  public static final com.typesafe.sbt.osgi.SbtOsgi$ MODULE$;
  public static {};
  public scala.collection.Seq<sbt.Init<sbt.Scope>.Setting<?>> settings();
  public scala.collection.Seq<sbt.Init<sbt.Scope>.Setting<?>> projectSettings();
  public scala.collection.Seq<sbt.Init<sbt.Scope>.Setting<?>> buildSettings();
  public scala.collection.Seq<sbt.Init<sbt.Scope>.Setting<?>> globalSettings();
  public com.typesafe.sbt.osgi.OsgiKeys$ OsgiKeys();
  public scala.collection.Seq<sbt.Init<sbt.Scope>.Setting<?>> osgiSettings();
  public scala.collection.Seq<sbt.Init<sbt.Scope>.Setting<?>> defaultOsgiSettings();
}
```

As one can see, it extends `sbt.Plugin`, but not the expected `sbt.Plugins`. The solution is to wait for an upstream fix.

Answer (score 0):

My response to [sbt/sbt#1844](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1844)

> If I believe the timestamp on https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-osgi/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/ The snapshot has not been updated since 05-Jan-2014 22:07, which matches the date on sbt/sbt-osgi@c6dd29a. At the time auto plugin was not released yet.